# Highcharts Scatter, plotting 3 days data on 12AM to 12PM of one day x-axis

Tags: java, highcharts

I have data of 3 days and we have following requirement.

1- X-Axis must be 12AM to 12PM with 2 hour interval. 
2- All days data should be plotted on time between 12AM to 12PM. 
3- I am not going to show 3 days chart with interval of 2 hours with 3 different slots like 
12AM...... 12PM of one day, 
12AM........12PM of 2nd day, 
and 12AM.........12PM of 3rd day.

How can i plot different days data in scatter chart?

you can see in below image.

[image]

above image contains 3 days data with the technique given below,

firstly i get the data from database and extract all dates, and added first date of range in the date timestamp, and my x-axis was just start day time of range's first day and last day time of range's first day.

*keep in mind localization is implemented as well. (data is populating as per client timezone)

client/ User = GMT +5
Server       = UTC

Now problem is that with this solution is, User selected date range 1-sep-2015 to 3-sep-2015, and user logged the data on 12AM of 1st sept 2015 GMT +5, it saved in DB UTC 7PM of 31 aug 2015, this data is not being plot on the chart because it go outside the range because x-axis is start day time of 1st sep 2015 to end start day time of 2nd sep 2015.

Now can you suggest any solution of this ?

Comment: You keep saying 12AM to 12PM, but that's only midnight to noon or 00:00 to 12:00... your chart shows 24 hours, 12AM to 12AM. So you really mean 00:00 to 23:59, right?

Comment: @dcsohl yes i really mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the plotting itself down; this is mostly a data retrieval question as I understand it.

So take the time range you want in local time (Sep-01 00:00 to Sep-03 23:59) and convert it to UTC (Aug-31 19:00 to Sep-03 18:59). Run your query for events in that time range, and then for each event you get back, convert it back to local time.

You may be able to do all the timezone conversions inside the database itself, depending on what database you are using; if not, doing it in the business logic is not a big deal at all with the dataset size you seem to be working with.

Comment: i have already done this .. but please read question properly again @dcsohl

Comment: So this is answer for your question or not, becuase is marked as proper.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell me what I'm misunderstanding, rather than just tell me to "read the question properly".

Comment: this is not data retrieval issue, i am retrieving in UTC plotting data as client timezone, data is retrieve but when go to point it missed logically as per timezone conversion it should be plot. @dcsohl

Comment: Let me give an example: suppose there is a data point at 02:00 on Sep-01. In the DB it is stored as Aug-31 21:00. User asks for Sep-01 00:00 to Sep-03 23:59. You convert this range to UTC (Aug-31 19:00 to Sep-03 18:59) and retrieve data for that range. *This includes the data point stored as Aug-31 21:00 UTC*. You then convert each data point back to local time, and my data point, Aug-31 21:00 UTC becomes Sep-01 02:00 local time again, and you plot it at 02:00. So tell me, how am I misunderstanding things and how is this not a data retrieval problem?